# How do I add a Commerce product type to a feature?

Tags: commerce, features

I have a custom product type that I created in my local dev environment and I'm trying to export it into a feature.

However, I can't seem to find where the product type is stored in the Features module UI.  I found the permissions (Product: View Own *Custom* Products) and the field instances (commerce_product-*custom*-commerce_license_role) but I don't see the product type itself.

Instead, when I enable the feature on production, I get the following error message:

> Warning in features rebuild of custom_module. No module defines permission
>   "view any commerce_product entity of bundle custom_product_type_machinename".

When I export to production, the product type is not created.  Where are the Commerce product types in the Features UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, product type export is not supported in the core Commerce module.  Instead, you need to install the [Commerce Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_features) module.

Comment: Hah, beat me to it yourself. ; )